# read.delim() getting multiple rows with 0 column

Tags: r

I am trying to read this table using `read.delim()`as using this commands

```
                          son_1   son_2   son_3   lgr_7   lgr_8   lgr_9
LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_4       0       0       0       0       0       0
LOC_Os12g06130.1:exon_1       0       0       0       0       0       0
LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_5       0       0       0       0       0       0
LOC_Os05g51110.1:exon_10     13      24      21     199       7      68
LOC_Os12g06130.1:exon_2       0       0       0       0       0       0
LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_6       0       0       0       0       0       0
LOC_Os05g51110.1:exon_11     30      59      38     137      15     134
```

Code:

```
dim(countTable)
# [1] 312500      0
countTable <- read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt", sep="\t", row.names=1, col.names=1)
dim(countTable)
# [1] 312500      0
countTable <- read.table("htseqCountTable.txt", sep="\t", row.names=1)
dim(countTable)
# [1] 312501      0
countTable <-read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt", sep="\t")
dim(countTable)
# [1] 312500      1
```

With this output I am not sure why I am getting blank columns(0) and multiple rows in it?

Comment: What do you think `row.names=1, col.names=1` is doing? Remove it, and it should work fine, why do you have them? I tried with `tab` delimited file and `read.delim` works fine. Are you sure you have tabs as separator?

Comment: 'row.names =1 and col.names =1' used here to ignore first column and row as i need to put only numerical value in my matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mr. Omley

> countTable <-read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt",  sep="")
>   dim(countTable)
>   `[1] 312500      2`

earlier this is what i was getting with `sep=""`

```
        X.                                  son_1.son_2.son_3.lgr_7.lgr_8.lgr_9
    1   LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_4,0,0,0,0,0,0 NA
    2   LOC_Os12g06130.1:exon_1,0,0,0,0,0,0 NA
    3   LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_5,0,0,0,0,0,0 NA
    4   LOC_Os05g51110.1:exon_10,13,24,21,199,7,68  NA
    5   LOC_Os12g06130.1:exon_2,0,0,0,0,0,0 NA
    6   LOC_Os08g25350.1:exon_6,0,0,0,0,0,0 NA
    7   LOC_Os05g51110.1:exon_11,30,59,38,137,15,134    NA
    8   LOC_Os12g06130.1:exon_3,167,128,213,605,293,484 NA
```

but when i change from sep="" to sep= ","

```
   > countTable <-read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt",  sep=",")
   > dim(countTable)
    [1] 312500      7
```

i got result as i want thankx for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Use `sep = ""` instead of `sep = "/t"`.

`row.names = 1` doesn't make sense for me. Reason for getting a single column when you read is because your data is not tab separated.

> **row.names**
>   a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the
>   actual row names, or a single number giving the column of the table
>   which contains the row names, or character string giving the name of
>   the table column containing the row names.
>
> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than
>   the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the
>   row names. Otherwise if row.names is missing, the rows are numbered.
>
> Using row.names = NULL forces row numbering. Missing or NULL row.names
>   generate row names that are considered to be ‘automatic’ (and not
>   preserved by as.matrix).
>
> **col.names**
>   a vector of optional names for the variables. The default
>   is to use "V" followed by the column number.

Comment: as in        `countTable <-read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt", sep="\t")
dim(countTable).
# [1] 312500      1 `     

m still getting only one column but my table has 6 column (only numerical data)
`> countTable <-read.delim("htseq.csv",  sep="")
> dim(countTable)
[1] 312500      2`
 now m getting only 2 col
`> countTable <-read.delim("htseqCountTable.txt",  sep="")
> dim(countTable)
[1] 312500      2`

Comment: `.csv` stands for Comma separates values. When you read a csv file, your delimiter should be a comma, i.e, `sep = ","`. If the data in your file `htseqCountTable.txt` is as stated in your question, then `sep = ""` should work. If doesn't, please display few rows from that 2 column table you got.